# Does Databricks provide a recommended spark parameters for a given cluster and dataset?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, bigdata

I just created a 7 node spark cluster with each worker having 8GB memory and 4 cores. Its not a huge cluster but fails with **"GC overhead limit exceeded"**
for only 10GB of data for a simple terasort.

I want to know how do I decide these basic parameters for a spark cluster so that the job does not fail as the data size grows.

1. num of executors
2. num of partitions
3. parallelism
4. executor cores
5. executor memory

I don't mind job running slow if not configured correctly but processes dying because of lack of memory is a big red flag.

Answer (score 2):

Some information like spark version, input format (text, parquet, orc), compression, etc would certainly help.

But in short the following is generally the thumb rule.

1. num-executors - This is total number of executors your entire cluster will devote for this job. Executor can contain one or more tasks. One would tend to think one node = one executor. It is better to have more than one executor per node. More on this later in the answer.
2. executor-cores - This is total number of cores (tasks) per executor. In your case, starting point is 4 core per executor (i.e. per node).
3. executor-memory - Total memory per executor. This is shared by all tasks or cores in the executor.

Most likely configuration (but less effective)
num-executors=7, executor-cores=4, executor-memory=8g
In this case, one executor is shared by 4 tasks. If one of them fails entire executor is marked as failed.

Better configuration
num-executors=14 (2 per node), executor-cores=2 (2 per executor), executor-memory=3g (3g per executor, leaving 2g for rest of the processes)

Please note that 1 core per executor is also not good as executor startup time may be too much in this case.

In this case, you are dividing the resources to avoid killing the entire executor.

Parallelism
This depends on format of your input data.